# mutable styles object for inline-style react components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, inline

I have a styles obj

```
let styles = {
  step_div:{
    height:'150px',
  } 
}
```

I want to render some div objects that have each their own color

```
class Layout extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      steps_array:[
        {title:'Intro',
          types:['Gate Keeper', 'Target Prospect'],
          color:'blue'},
        {title:'Grab Attention',
          types:['Name Drop', 'Product Value'],
          color:'yellow'},
        {title:'Disqualify Statement',
          types:[],
          color:'yellow'}]
```

Looping through the array, adding the border color to the styles is giving me an error

```
  make_structure(){
    let rows = []
    let data = this.state.steps_array
    data.forEach((i, key)=>{
      let style = styles.step_div
      style.border="1px solid "+i.color //each items color property
      let row = (
        <Row>
          <div  style={style}>
            {i.title}
          </div>
        </Row>
      )
      rows.push(row)
    })
    return rows
  }
```

error

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'border' of object '#<Object>'
```

Comment: use Object.assign()

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: can you show `styles` object ?

Comment: Thanks Dinesh! that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this.

```
let style = {...styles.step_div,border:'1px solid'+i.color};
```

Comment: let style = {{...styles.step_div,border:'1px solid'+i.color}};